# toSearchableArray() in Laravel Scout overwrites owner

Tags: laravel-5.4, algolia, laravel-scout

One user can create, edit and delete a model. All other users can update that model as well (by liking it). Now, when a user who is **not** the creator of an entry updates the model, the creator gets overwritten by the one who updated it.

Basically, this is what happens when pushing data to the Algolia index:

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    $user = \Auth::user();

    $meetingData = array(
        'username' => $user->name,
        ...
    );

    return $meetingData;
}
```

When the record is being updated by a different user than the creator, $user  is not the creator, but the one updating the record. That way, the creator gets overwritten, which I need to avoid.

Is it possible to update only a single value within a index record, and not the whole record? The only way I could see to update a model is by doing something like this in the controller:

```
$meeting = Meet::find($id);
$meeting->interests = implode(',', $currentLikesArray);
$meeting->save();
```

But this updates the whole record, which screws with the creator user id.

Answer (score 0):

My initial recommendation would be that you should be saving 'Likes' in their own table, and having a one-to-many relationship between Meetings and Likes. That way you can do things like easily allow users to see what meetings they have liked etc, since you would have a one-to-many relationship between your users and their Likes too. 
Doing this means you don't have to update the entire meeting object for a simple Like (and thus overwrite the original creator). Instead, you create a related Like object with its own creator.

Since you're not doing it that way and instead storing likes on the meeting objects themselves, you could do something along the following lines,

In your Meeting class, you presumably already have a relation to a user:

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

With the above, in your controller function for **creating** the meeting you're then saving the currently logged in user as the creator of the meeting e.g.

```
$meeting->user_id = $request->user()->id;
```

With that relationship in place, we now have access to the User object related to the meeting, So when you come to the searchable array settings you can just do:

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    $meetingData = $this->toArray();

    $meetingData['username'] = $this->user->name;
    ...

    return $meetingData;
}
```

since your meeting object has a related user object, you can just reference that for the username. If someone else has updated the object with a Like, then it's still the original creator that will be saved for the username attribute, as you're not overwriting it with the currently logged in user.

Hope that helps!